# How can I create a loop of this code for interpolation?

Tags: python, loops

```
x_sync_1=x[0]
y_sync_1=np.interp(x_sync_1,a,b)
x_sync_2=x[1]
y_sync_2=np.interp(x_sync_2,a,b)
x_sync_3=x[2]
y_sync_3=np.interp(x_sync_3,a,b)
x_sync_4=x[3]
y_sync_4=np.interp(x_sync_4,a,b)
x_sync_5=x[4]
y_sync_5=np.interp(x_sync_5,a,b)
```

How can I loop this codes? I try to interpolate all. Normally it works but when I try to create a `for` loop it does not work.

```
for i in range (1,5):
    x[i-1]=x_sync_[i]
    y_sync_[i]=np.interp(x_sync_[i],a,b)
```

the error is `x_sync_` is not defined.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Make a list out of all `x_sync_*` and `y_sync_*` variables. `x_sync = [0] * 5, y_sync = [0] * 5`. Then looping will be trivial

Comment: for i in range (1,5):
    x_sync_[i]=x[i-1]
    y_sync_[i]=np.interp(x_sync_[i],a,b)

Answer (score 0):

Numbered variables are an anti-pattern. Use a list instead.

```
x_syncs = []
y_syncs = []

for i in range(5):
    x_syncs.append(x[i])
    y_syncs.append(np.interp(x[i], a, b))
```

or

```
for v in x[:5]:
    x_syncs.append(v)
    y_syncs.append(np.interp(v, a, b))
```

or

```
x_syncs = x[:5]
y_syncs = [np.interp(v, a, b) for v in x_syncs]
```